# Mapping neo4j ogm query results to java objects

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm collecting infos from a neo4j db, but the values I return are picked out from multiple nodes, so what I'm basically returning is a table with some properties. For this example, let's say I return the properties `color:String`, `name:String`, `count:String`. I query these results using `session.query(*QUERY*, queryParams)`.
Now, when I get the results, I want to map it to an existing Java Object, that I created to hold this data. This is kind of different to the 'normal' mapping, as in general, you want to map your graph nodes to objects that represent those nodes. Here, my POJOs have nothing to do with the graph nodes.
I managed to do this using custom `CompositeAttributeConverter` classes for each of my data-objects, but I feel there must be a better solution than writing a new class for every new object.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [executing arbitrary Cypher queries](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities:cypher-queries) using the Session object. You can get an `Iterable<Map<String,Object>>` from the returned `Result` object, which you could process over or just output to a collection of Map results.

Or, if you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) installed, you can always write up a query to return your results as a JSON string, and convert that to JSON objects in Java with the appropriate library and use those as needed.