# Java + SpringBoot + Neo4j : Is there a way to bypass the OGM?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cypher

I would like to perform Cypher queries from my Java code and get JSON replies, just as I would get in Neo4j's Browser app. That is, get unmapped results, and retrieve the nodes and relationships descriptions I would get otherwise. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need to be explicitly JSON or just you need a way to returned non-typed data? Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43499345/3079891

Comment: My question was more like, how could I get the JSON-formatted result I would get in the Neo4j browser, such as :`[ { "n": { "identity": 1461, "labels": [ "BaseNode"  ], "properties": { "yadyadah": "" } } } ]`. Getting the labels'n'all would help.